# Javascript: how to create an infinite-loop of promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I want to write in Javascript the following pseudo-code:

```
function asyncOperation() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ....
   }
}

while (true) { 
    result = asyncOperation()
    if result is good then break the loop;
    else loop again
}
```

I'll explain it in words: asyncOperation uses a Promise, for example an AJAX call. I want that if the promise is rejected, then asyncOperation will be invoked again. Do you know how it can be done in Javascript?

Comment: Are you on a platform which supports async/await?  I feel like this would be extremely simple using a while with a flag, and a try/catch which sets this flag accordingly.

Comment: async/await is a syntactic sugar of Promises.

Comment: Yes, but not all platforms support it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The answer is simple: You have **ABSOLUTELY NO** ways to do that without making your calling code asynchronous.

Comment: Are you just asking for a promise retry? There are lots of answers with a generic "retry" function that retries a function until the promise returned from it is fulfilled - and there are librareis that do fancy things like exponential backoff for retries and delays

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, can you name some of these libraries?

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-retry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use a loop, then you will have to use `await` because otherwise, your loop will just run forever and never give the asynchronous operation any cycles to actually process its completion:

```
while (true) { 
    result = await asyncOperation()
    if (good result) {
         break;
    }
}
```

This, of course, needs to be inside a function declared as `async`.

---

Before `await`, the usual way to do this would be with a local function and a recursive-looking structure (that by the way does not have any stack build-up from recursion because of the async operation):

```
function run() {
    return asyncOperation().then(result => {
        if (good result) {
            return result;
        } else {
            // try again
            return run();
        }
    });
}

run().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

And, typically you would insert some small delay before calling the `asyncOperation()` again in order to avoid hammering the target server.  And, you would have either a timeout or a max number of retries to avoid a situation where this loop runs forever.

Comment: It's definitely a valid answer, but as you know recursion can be very not efficient. Is there any option to do it without a recursion?

Comment: @CrazySynthax - It isn't really recursion because of the asynchronous nature here.  There is no stack build-up as the stack fully unwinds before the `.then()` handler is called.  And, why don't you just use the `await` option which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this just be sufficient:

```
async function loopUntilTrue() {
  let success = false;

  while (!success) {
    try {
      await asyncOperation();
      success = true;
    } catch {
      success = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a very long way to write `while(!(await asyncOperation());`

Answer (score -1):

I created a loop function to do that

```js
let count = 0;
function asyncOperation() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (count < 10) {
      console.log('reject', count++);
      reject();
      return;
    }
    resolve(console.log('resolve', count));
  });
}

async function loop() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      await asyncOperation();

      break;
    } catch {
      continue;
    }
  }
}

loop();
```

The result is this:

```
reject 0
reject 1
reject 2
reject 3
reject 4
reject 5
reject 6
reject 7
reject 8
reject 9
resolve 10
```